# What is the best way to filter and sort data in react and DRF

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, django-filter

I have a back-end built using Django Rest Framework and front-end served using React. I'm having a Filter component and Sort By component. I receive the `products` data as a json from back-end. I want to be able to filter by few fields such as `category, brand, price etc` and sort based on fields as well like `ascending category, descending price etc`.
Basically i'd want my url to look like this

```
{{baseUrl}}/products?category=a&category=b&brand=c&sort=category_desc
```

My question is

- What is the best way to filter data i.e should i send data to back-end to filter using `django-filters` or filter using a javascript `array.filter()` ?
- Should i sort using `django-filter's` `OrderFilter` or custom `javascript's` `array.sort()`
- How to synchronise the query params in front-end with both filters and sortby conditions.

I'm new to this, so if there is any blog post or document i can go through, that would be really helpful too along with your inputs. Thanks in advance!